# Launch Chrome User from Command Line with Proxy

Tags: google-chrome, proxy

How would I launch Chrome User from Command Line with Proxy? I tried `chrome --proxy-server="https://206.246.75.178:3129"`

But it does not work because the proxy is not set.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I managed to do it is by using `--temp-profile` option:

```
$ chromium --temp-profile --proxy-server="localhost:12345"
```

As you probably noticed it's not chrome but chromium. But I hope it works for you as well.

Not sure why it works this way though...